# Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express

I'm trying to insert data on my database. I couldn’t access my postgresSql database, all the time I I try to execute a query, it shows me this error message:

Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

I have changed my postgre password in hope to see it changing. But even so the error persisted.

Comment: In all the related questions with this error, it turned out the password they were setting never got used. That sounds exactly like your problem.too.

Comment: That error does not come from PostgreSQL. Perhaps from OpenSSL? We can not even guess, if you don't tell us which version of which software you have installed on client and server, what the relevant configuration is and how exactly you are trying to connect.